# running android project with multiple external jars and sources

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, jar

I am trying to compile an adroid project using ant which contains multiple sources and external 3rd party jars.
It works fine with eclipse but i require it to run through command line using ant.

my custom_rules.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project name="CustomRules">
     <target name="-pre-build" >
             <copy todir="tmp-src" >
                     <fileset dir="src" includes="**" />
                     <fileset dir="talkAndroid" includes="**" />
                     <fileset dir="commonAndroid" includes="**" />
                    <fileset dir="cocos2dAndroid" includes="**" />
             </copy>
             <classpath id="classpath" description="The default classpath.">
                     <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
                     <fileset dir="external_libs">
                             <include name="*.jar"/>
                     </fileset>
             </classpath>
     </target>
     <target name="-post-build" >
             <delete dir="tmp-src" />
     </target> </project>
```

it isn't working for `external_libs` and unable to find external libraries, if I copy these jars from `external_libs` to libs folder ... duplicate class found errors are generated!

What should I do?